# Geting Cross Threads error while using Threads

Tags: multithreading

I am using two forms and one thread for form1 , when thread of form1 is using data of form2 two at run time i got error

```
"system can not allow you to make cross threading!"
```

Comment: Post your code. Also, is this C#? WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just add this at form1 load :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }
```

You are getting this error because form has its own threads running that's why when your thread reach to get data from form2 threads get interruption and error generated

Comment: This is a horrible hack with a highly speculative explanation.

Comment: That's about on par with advising someone to put black tape across all the warning indicator lights in their car, so that it'll never have any problems again.